# when I use npm to create react app ,I get this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm having a problem with npm, I cant create react app

when I do `npm init react-app my-app` or `npx create-react-app my-app` I get this error

```
C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react1>npm init react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react1\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ZAKARIA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-12T09_37_00_926Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react1
Done.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ZAKARIA\Desktop\react1
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app "my-app"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ZAKARIA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-12T09_36_53_140Z-debug-0.log
```

any idea how to solve this proplem

Comment: check network connectivity

Comment: no problem in network connection.

Comment: install fiddler and check connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to clean your cache using this command  `npm  cache clear --force` Then try again.